# Жесткая установка переменной JAVA_HOME в Linux

Tags: solaris, unix, map-reduce, java, linux

Пытаюсь запустить все демоны `hadoop` с помощью команды

```
./start-all.sh
```

с главного компьютера кластера. В результате выполнения несколько раз выдавало:

```
starting namenode, logging to /export/hadoop-1.0.1/libexec/../logs/hadoop--namenode-one.out
192.168.1.10: starting datanode, logging to /export/hadoop-1.0.1/libexec/../logs/hadoop-hadoop-datanode-myhost2.out
192.168.1.10: Error: JAVA_HOME is not set.
```

И это происходило несколько раз даже после выполнения на виртуальной машине с адресом `192.168.1.10` команды

```
hadoop@myhost2:~$ export JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk1.7.0_06
```

Скажите, пожалуйста, как жестко один раз закрепить переменную `JAVA_HOME`?

Comment: в .bash.profile прописать?

Comment: @Gorets вы хотели сказать в файл `/root/.bash_profile` (уточнить полный путь пожалуйста и имя)?

Comment: да, он самый

Answer (score 1):

зачем в /root/bash  ???
Вы ведь не собираетесь запускать джава приложения от рута?
В /etc/profile.d/ определить глобвальную переменную окружения для java
создав файл примерно java.sh(или любое название файла:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jre-openjdk
```

у меня установлена java 1.6

```
yum install java-devel
```

Answer (score 1):

Лучше всего прописывать необходимые переменные, в том числе `JAVA_HOME`, в файле `\etc\hadoop\hadoop-env.sh`.

Из плюсов:

- можно использовать отдельную JRE чисто для Hadoop'а
- независимо от того, под каким пользователем будут запущены демоны - будет использоваться заданная конфигурация
- проще поддерживать (в том числе переносить конфигурацию между нодами)

Answer (score 0):

можно еще жеще в /etc/bash.bashrc

написать export JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk1.7.0_06

Comment: @G1yyK можете уточнить имя файла. У меня в папке `/etc/bash/` есть папка `bash_completion.d` и три файла: `bash_completion.example`, `bashrc.example` и `inputrc.example`.

Comment: дистрибутив какой?
логически я бы переименовал файл bashrc.exemple в bashrc и прописал туда export. Более детальную информацию можно посмотреть на вики вашего дистрибутива по настройке bash